# Uniformization of Kodaira fibered surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, fibration

Consider a Kodaira fibration. i.e. a smooth non-isotrivial fibration $X\rightarrow C$ with $X$ a smooth complex surface and $C$ a smooth complex curve, such that both the genus of $C$ and genus of the fibers (which are complex curves) are at least $2$. By abuse of notation I call $X$ a Kodaira fibered surface. What is known about the structure of the universal cover of $X$? In particular, when is it a bounded symmetric domain? I know that $X$ is a minimal algebraic surface of general type and that the universal cover of $X$ can never be a ball in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

Comment: It is bounded domain (Bers) but is not symmetric: It is not a ball as you know and is not a polydisk.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! could you give a reference about your answer? also, do you mean that from the fact that it is not neither a ball nor a polydisk, follows that it is not a bounded symmetric domain?

Comment: Also, what is your argument that it is not a polydisk?

Comment: I think I got my first answer: since it is simply connected you are using the decomposition in to irreducible components: so it is either a ball or a polydisc. But still I don't know how you argue that it is not a polydisk?

Comment: OK, I think I got my second answer too! it is not a polydisc because otherwise $X$ will be a product of curves and this contradicts for example the positivity of $c_{2}$. Am I right? Is this also your argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the arguments to exclude polydisk and the ball (there are no other complex 2-dimensional bounded symmetric domains: In fact, one can do without this and argue that any domain other than the ball would have rank $\ge 2$ and, hence, Margulis superrigidity theorem would apply).

1. Kefeng Liu ("Geometric height inequalities", Math. Research Letters, 3 (1996), 693–702) proved that a compact complex-hyperbolic surface cannot admit a  holomorphic submersion to a Riemann surface.  This excludes the complex ball.
2. Consider the 2-dimensional polydisk $D^2$ and a group $\Gamma$ acting discretely, holomorphically and cocompactly on $D^2$. Then $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $Isom(D^2)$ and by Margulis' superrigidity theorem either $\Gamma$ is reducible or it is superrigid, and , ehnce, does not admit an epimorphism to a surface group. The second is impossible in the case of fibrations over Riemann surfaces, the first contradicts non-isotriviality assumption in the question.

On the other hand, the universal cover of your complex manifold $X$ is a certain bounded domain in ${\mathbb C}^2$: This result could be found in

P.A. Griffiths, Complex-analytic properties of certain Zariski open sets on algebraic varieties. Ann. of Math. (2) 94 (1971), 21–51.

who proves it using Bers' simultaneous uniformization.

Comment: Dear Misha. Thanks a lot for your beautiful answer. Some questions: You said: "there are no other complex 2-dimensional bounded symmetric domains". I am not an expert in this area so maybe what I say is just stupid: As far as I know, the irreducible BSD fall in to two $6$ classes classified by Cartan. There is a class $IV(n)$ of complex dimension $n$ which is given by the Lie sphere or $IV(n)=\frac{SO_{0}(n,2)}{SO(n)\times SO(2)}$. Apparenlty, for $n=2$, this has dimension $2$ and is not a ball and not a polydisk. Then why do you say that in dim=2 there is no BSD except the ball and polydisk?

Comment: Also, could you a little bit elucidate your meaning of "The second is impossible in the case of fibrations over Riemann surfaces, the first contradicts non-isotriviality assumption in the question." why the second is impossible for fibrations apver Riemann surfaces and Why does thge first contradicts the non-isotriviality. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @DariusMath: $IV(2)$ is the same as the bi-disk. I also explained in my answer (1st sentence) how you can avoid the classification.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice it! Thank you very much for your answers. It really helped me a lot. By the way, now that IV(2) is a polydisk, I think in addition to this argument, the argument that I gave in my comments above also work: It is not a ball by the Arakelov inequalities and not a polzdisk (hence a product of curves) since  otherwise $c_{2}$ will vanish.

Comment: @DariusMath: Suppose you have an irreducible lattice $\Gamma$. Then Margulis' theorem implies that $\Gamma$ has finite abelianization. This implies that $\Gamma$ cannot have an epimorphism to a the fundamental group of a Riemann surface of genus $\ge 1$. But the long exact sequence of a fibration (applied to Kodaira's fibration) implies that $\pi_1(X)$ maps onto $\pi_1(C)$.

Comment: @DariusMath: Could you explain how to exclude the ball using Arakelov? The only proof that I know is by appealing to Liu's theorem.

Comment: Dear Misha: A ball will satisfy $c_{1}^{2}=3c_{2}$ by Yau's result. Now $c_{1}^{2} = K_{X/C}^2 + 2(2g-2)(2q-2)$. On the other hand, $ c_{2} = (2g-2)(2q-2)$. Subsitiuting gives us:  $K_{X/C}^{2} = (2g-2)(2q-2)$ which contradicts the "strict canonical class inequality"

Comment: @DariusMath: How do you prove the strict class inequality without Liu's paper?

Comment: Misha: It's been proven by Vojta using Arakelov theory many years before Liu (in fact, Vojta's paper appears as a reference in Liu's paper). Look at this: Vojta, P., Diophantine inequalities and Arakelov theory , in Lang, Introduction to Arakelov Theory (1988), Springer-Verlag, 155–178. Liu's approach is more differential geometric.

Comment: Misha: I still haven't understood one point: Why the lattice Γ in your answer can not be reducibe? in your explanatation you excluded the case where Γ is irreducible by Margulis result. Why Γ can not be reducible too?

Comment: @DariusMath: In this case, a (torsion-free) reducible lattice is either a product of two lattices $\Gamma_i$, $i=1,2$, each acting in the 1-dimensional disk, or is an index 2 extension of such lattice by an element which swaps the factors of $D^2=D\times D$. In the first case, you clearly get an isotrivial family. In the second case, the quotient manifold cannot be fibered.

Comment: Dear Misha. Thanks alot for your complete answer.

Comment: Dear Misha, I am sorry but it is not completely clear to me why in the first case we get an isotrivial family: in this case the surface $X$ will be a quotient of $D\times D$ by $\Gamma_{1}\times \Gamma_{2}$ and is equal to $D/ \Gamma_{1} \times D/\Gamma_{2}$. But it doesnot imply simply that the family is isotrivial or am I missing some points?

Comment: @DariusMath: The only fibrations are projections to the factors, the surface $X$ is the product and the family is trivial in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. But exactly what I don't understand is why the only fibrations in this case are the trivial ones. I should think more on this and prove it!

Comment: @DariusMath: The proof of this (that I know) comes from algebra: If $F_1, F_2$ are two surface groups (of genus $\ge 2$) and $F_3< F_1\times F_2$ is a normal surface  subgroup, then it has to be a (finite index) normal subgroup in one of the direct factors. Given this, in case when $F_3$ is $\pi_1$ of a fiber in a topological fibration, $F_3$ has to equal one of the factors. From there, you use the fact that two homotopic holomorphic maps from a compact Kahler manifold to the same hyperbolic Riemann surface have to be equal. You can probably fill in the details yourself now.

Comment: Dear Misha. Thanks a lot for your help. What are the best references to learn about this surface group stuff and the relations with surface fibrations?

Comment: I will write details as an update to my answer, so it is more visible to others who might be interested.

Answer (score 6):

If an algebraic surface has the bidisk as universal cover, then, by Hirzebruch's proportionality theorem, its topological index is 0 (the index is 1/3 (c_1^2 - 2 c_2)).
But Kodaira proved that for Kodaira  fibrations the index is strictly positive.
To exclude the case that the universal covering is the ball, where 
c_1^2 = 3 c_2, again by Hirzebruch's theorem, is harder and was done by Kefeng Liu. You may look in my article with Rollenske for more results on Kodaira fibrations. 
Regards, Fabrizio Catanese.

Comment: Very beautiful answer ! Thank you and I'm very glad to be the first one who receives an answer from you professor Catanese.

Comment: There is also another paper by A. Nadel which is linked with this topic (\emph{Semisimplicity of the group of biholomorphisms of the universal covering of a compact complex manifold with ample canonical bundle}). In this really beautiful paper Nadel shwos for instance that the automorphism groups of the universal cover a canonically polarized surface (it is the case for a Kodaira surface) are very constraints: if it's positive dimensional, it's the automorphism group of the ball or of the bidisk (else it's a discrete group and it reduces almost to the fundamental group of the surface).